# VS Code: running ASP.NET SPA with Angular 4 and using NodeServices options Launch With Debugging

Tags: asp.net, angular, visual-studio-code, node-inspector, vscode-tasks

I have tried to launch in VS Code my SPA project (Angular 4 + ASP.NET) and I am getting errors. This errors are cause by:

```
 // Add JavaScript services.
            services.AddNodeServices(options => {
                // https://github.com/aspnet/JavaScriptServices/tree/dev/src/Microsoft.AspNetCore.SpaServices#debugging-your-javascripttypescript-code-when-it-runs-on-the-server
                options.LaunchWithDebugging = true; 
                options.DebuggingPort = 9229;
            });
```

This options should enable debugging my javascript/typscript code while it is prerendered on the server. But the problem is that this configuration is deprecated.

[image: Error while running application in the browser]

It means that I should use `node --inspect` instead of `node --debug` But how can I achieve this in VS Code, or ASP.NET Core project to force that `dotnet run` command will start appropriate **node debugging mode.**

Comment: What version of Node are you using?

Comment: node -v shows version v7.9.0

Comment: I'm struck with the same error message :(

Answer (score 1):

This issue is caused by change in Node.js between versions 4.x and later. The required changes or modifications to fix this issue are already done for NodeServices package which is compatible with .Net Core 2.0 (Fix is not available for .Net Core 1.0)

So following are the available options

1. Downgrade to Node 4.x which doesn't exhibit this problem *Or*
2. upgrade to ASP.NET Core 2.0 Preview 2, which includes the latest version of NodeServices in which this issue is fixed.

Thanks to Steve for clarifying in below thread
https://github.com/aspnet/JavaScriptServices/issues/1084#issuecomment-313083926